# how to use the private variables's value outside the parallel region

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a parallel fortran code with OpenMP. This is the parallel part of code:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(iconf,d,randx,                   &
!$OMP& randy,randz,unit_cg,theta1,theta2,theta3,fr1,fr2,fr3,Q,          &
!$OMP& plproduct_avg,correlation_term) 

      allocate(randx(num),randy(num),randz(num),unit_cg(num),           &
     &         fr1(num),fr2(num),fr3(num),theta1(order,num),            &
     &         theta2(order,num),theta3(order,num),                     &
     &         Q(nfftdim1,nfftdim2,nfftdim3))


!$OMP DO 

      do 250 iconf = 1,1600
       write(6,*)'configuration number',iconf

       {some calculations}

       do 350 d = 0,int(nfft1/2)
        write(6,*)'correlation term of iconf =',iconf,'d=',d,           &
     &             correlation_term(d,iconf)
350    continue

250   continue

!$OMP END DO

      deallocate(randx,randy,randz,unit_cg,fr1,fr2,fr3,theta1,theta2,   &
     &           theta3,Q)

!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

As it is clear, this loop calculates the `correlation_term(iconf)` (they are private) and prints them on output file correctly. But when I use these variables outside the parallel region, all of them are zero.

How can I use the values of `correlation_term(iconf)` calculated in parallel region, outside it?

Comment: Why should it be `private`? You parallelised the loop over `iconf`, which is the index for accessing `correlation_term`. So my first impression is (unless there is a good reason for it to be private) that `correlation_term` should be `shared`, which would solve your problem...

Comment: Thank you Gilles. I edited the question, and added some lines that I thought they are irrelevant. You are right, when I make the `correlation_term` shared, the values of them outside of parallel region are non zero. But I'm worried about `d` argument of `correlation_term` .

Comment: The second dimension for `correlation_term` doesn't change the problem. As long as each thread only accesses its own slice of `correlation_term`, the array can be shared without any issue. Only if you have cross-references across threads becomes it trickier. Have you?

Comment: No, all loops are completely independent.

Comment: So having the array shared is no problem.